# Meeting Schedule question. How do I convert this code to MySQL(or any other SQL)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

The question is:

> Using SQL find minimum number of available rooms required for all
>   meeting to take place without delays and on time.

Here is the schedule of meetings.

```
    start   end
     8       9.15
    10      14
    13.2    15.2
    13.55   16.45
    14      17.45
    14.05   17.45
```

I found a way to do it in Python using pandas but not sure how to make it work in SQL. I found some solutions but those were simulation-like and I think there is a more elegant way to solve this problem.

Here is the Python code:

```
number_of_rooms = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    rooms = 1
    for j in range(len(data)):
        if data['start'][i]<data['end'][j] and data['start'][i]>data['start'][j]:
            rooms = rooms + 1
        number_of_rooms.append(rooms)
```

Comment: Whats the data variable? Can you put down a working Python (fiddle) somewhere and post the link? And what are the expected results your not printing annything?

Comment: https://rextester.com/KHCPY41517

Comment: "Using SQL find minimum number of available rooms required for all meeting to take place without delays and on time." Yes but what should be the answer? i assume "time slots"  `8       9.15
    10      14
    13.2    15.2` (first three records)  needs 1 room and "time slots" `13.55   16.45
    14      17.45
    14.05   17.45` (last three records) needs two rooms.. So the minimum available rooms required for all meetings for that complete day is two? Because the first three records and the last three records "time slots" do not overlap?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a translation of your logic in a SQL query :

```
SELECT i.start, i.end, COUNT(*) number_of_rooms
FROM rooms i
LEFT JOIN rooms j ON i.start < j.end AND i.start  > j.start
GROUP BY i.start, i.end
```

The query processes each record in the table (alias `i`). The self-join pulls in all records in the same table (`j`) that satisfy the time interval overlap condition. Then the `GROUP BY` clause aggregates the data for each record of `i`, and `COUNT()` gives you the number of matching records in `j`.

Comment: think that it is better to use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(j.start)` which can be counting `NULL` values from the `j` alias you are `LEFT JOINING` so it might count some 0 values for some record(s)... Besides that this query seams to be solid to get the job done so still +1

Comment: @RaymondNijland : yes I think you are right, also since in the OP code, `rooms` is initialized with `1` for each iteration. Thanks.

Comment: @Strawberry : I think OP is trying to count how many records are overlapping with the current one (+1 to include the current record in the count), wouldn’t that make sense ?

Comment: @GMB I think the OP wants to know how many rooms are required.